# Set achemso title/author/affiliation font the same as main text

Tags: fonts, achemso

Since by default `achemso` produces fonts for title/author/affiliation different from main text (as given in [`achemso` demo pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/achemso/achemso-demo.pdf)). How can I set the font throughout the document to the default document of main text (which I presume is Times).

```
\documentclass[,manuscript=article]{achemso}

\author{Author1}
\affiliation{Department}
\title{Title}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I ask why you want to fiddle with things? (The set up is all CM, sanserif in the headers, serif in the body.)

Comment: It just looks better to have all the fonts consistent (especially title). I am not sure if ACS people do not recommend changing the default fonts though. Is that the case?

Comment: The recommendation is to change only what you have to: the class is for journal submission and alterations are agreed with the ACS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst not advertised, there are a series of abstractions in the class to set this:

- `\affilfont`
- `\authorfont`
- `\emailfont`
- `\titlefont`

all of which can be set to whatever you like.